# Installing Windows Web Server 2008 on VPC 2007 Host OS - Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7

I'm running into an error when I try to install Windows Web Server 2008 x86 on a VPC I created with VPC 2007. Shortly after I enter the product key in the installation wizard it displays an error message that says:

> Windows installation encountered an error and needs to be restarted

Here's my info -

- Host OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Host Processor: i7
- Guest OS: Windows Web Server 2008 x86
- VPC Version: 2007

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your installation media is on the MVLS website, re-download it, check the checksum and then burn it to a new DVD. This is an error that has been associated with bad media or a corrupted ISO file at burn time.

If this is a TechNet license that you are entering, do not enter it at the time of installation. Sometimes this issue has come up with TechNet licenses. If you can continue without an error, perform a `sfc /scannow` to make sure that system files are not corrupted. You can enter a license key later.

The culprit in this is almost certainly a corrupted image. Either the original ISO or the media (or perhaps the lens in the CD-ROM drive, but that's less likely).